# Downloading report in pdf

Tags: pdf, shiny, report

I am creating an Shiny App following these instructions : The shiny app has the following specifications.

For the user interface:

fileInput to let the user upload a file. You can choose whether to restrict to one or multiple file extension.
actionButton that triggers verification on the file uploaded.
textOutput that prints the verification.
downloadButton in order to download a PDF report.
The server comprises three parts:

Read the file and save it into a reactive object data().
Verification of the file into a renderText. At least the type of data must be tested. Depending on your report and the particular application, more tests can be added (number of lines, number of columns, ...).
Production of the report into downloadHandler. The report is a Rmd file that is rendered within downloadHandler with the rmarkdown::render command. The format of the report must be PDF.
The report is provided as an additional .Rmd file. You can keep it simple, but at the very least, it should use the data() input by the user.

Here is the code for my shiny app :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
```

`

```
# Define ui
ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("upload", "Upload file",
            multiple = TRUE,
            accept = c(".csv",".pdf")),
  actionButton("goButton", "Verify File"),
  textOutput("verificationResult"),
  downloadButton("downloadReport", "Download PDF Report") 
)

#Define server 
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Reactive object 
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$upload)
    read.csv(input$upload$datapath)
  })

  # Verification of the file
  verification_result <- reactive({
    if (is.null(data())) {
      "Error: No data in the file."
    } else if (!grepl("\\.csv$", input$upload$name, ignore.case = TRUE)) {
      "Error: Uploaded file is not in the correct format (CSV)."
    } else {
      "File is verified successfully!"
    }
  })

  output$verificationResult <- renderText({
    verification_result()
  })

  # Production of the report
  output$downloadReport <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("report_", Sys.Date(), ".pdf", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      # Render the Rmd report
      rmarkdown::render(
        input = "/Users/meriem/Documents/GitHub/homework-3-mbenmust/report.Rmd",
        output_format = "pdf_document",
        output_file = file,
        params = list(data = data())
      )
    }
  )
  
}

# Run the Shiny app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have also added to my GitHub repository a file : report.Mkd with these parameters

---

### title: report
output: pdf_document
params:
data: "data"

After installing Latex, I have this error :

```
! sh: pdflatex: command not found

Error: LaTeX failed to compile report.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See report.log for more info.
In addition: Warning message:
In system2(..., stdout = if (use_file_stdout()) f1 else FALSE, stderr = f2) :
  error in running command
Execution halted

No LaTeX installation detected (LaTeX is required to create PDF output). You should install a LaTeX distribution for your platform: https://www.latex-project.org/get/

  If you are not sure, you may install TinyTeX in R: tinytex::install_tinytex()

  Otherwise consider MiKTeX on Windows - http://miktex.org

  MacTeX on macOS - https://tug.org/mactex/
  (NOTE: Download with Safari rather than Chrome _strongly_ recommended)

  Linux: Use system package manager
```

However when I run my code I only get a document in the Github repository named : report. tex , there is no pdf file download :(

Can anyone explain to me what doesn't work and how can I fix it please ?

Thank you in advance :-)